# CSS Selector confusion - How do I control style without overusing classes?

Tags: html, css

I decided to build a page around a responsive menu I found (I think in an answer here), when I got ready to work on the rest of the page I realized that all the CSS for the menu had been set to select and style all `ul, li, a` elements for the entire page. I tried adding selectors to each of the styled elements multiple ways, but every time something comes out messed up. Out of desperation I made classes/ids for each one, but that just makes the html look gross and still seems like I've messed up somewhere. Below is the offending css. 
Could someone point me in the right direction?

CSS-

```
body {
    margin:0

}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.menuBackground {
    background:#2f3036;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

.menuContainer {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right:1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    background:#2f3036;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background:#146ac3;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#2f3036;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background:#146ac3;
    color:#fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display:block;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    padding:0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden,.hidden:hover {
    display:block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:#146ac3;
    text-align:center;
    padding:16px 0;
    display:none;
    width:100%!important
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/
@media screen and (max-width : 760px) {
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position:static;
        display:none;
        white-space: initial;
    }

    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom:0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
    }

    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li,li a {
        width:100%;
    }

    /*Display 'show menu' link*/
    .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }

}
```

HTML-

```
<div class="menuContainer">
            <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu"><span class="uppercasebold">Show Menu</span></label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uppercasebold">Home</span></a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="uppercasebold">About</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="uppercasebold">Inventory</span> ￬</a>
                    <ul class="hidden">
                        <li><a href="#">New</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Used</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Custom Built</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uppercasebold">Forum</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uppercasebold">Contact</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.menuContainer` in front of everything you want to be styled specifically in that menu. And before that, style your ul / li for general use.

Comment: That's got me pretty close, but I've been looking at this for too long and must be missing one. Everything is fine until it shrinks to the smaller screen breakpoint. If it's not too much to ask could you glance at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1quekgz/)

Answer (score 1):

in order to dont mess up with your ongoing coding you have to "wrap-secure" your elements and specially your vulnerable tags (li,ul,a etc because u gona use them multiple times) so any change you do inside will affect only the "childs" of your "father" element.

so here are some you can do on your given code:

1. your class "menuContainer" is the one who must be used before your specific changes on your css, like ".menuContainer ul" , ".menuContainer a" etc
2. you have a class "uppercasebold" in every span inside your "menuContainer", so using ".menuContainer span {}" can remove all your "uppercasebold" classes
3. you need to have as much less conflicts in your coding, so use wiselely ".menuContainer li" will affect not only ".menucontainer ul li" but also ".menucontainer ul li ul li" , same with your other tags like ".menuContainer li a".
4. To affect ONLY your inner(second) li you can give it a class or id, or you can call ".menucontainer ul li ul li", but to affect your first li u have to give it a class or id.

Comment: Good point on the `span`, I suppose I don't completely follow you on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've messed up by adding lots of classes. You might check out Denise Jacobs' excellent series on [CSS Architecture](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-architectures-scalable-and-modular-approaches/), specifically the sections on OOCSS and SMACSS.

If you take the OOCSS approach, you'd scope your module with a single parent class and then use descendant selectors to target sub-elements and classes (basically what Vinc is suggesting).

In my opinion, the right approach is actually to add even more classes -- basically just class every element. That's more consistent with the SMACSS school of architecture. And for repeated styles like `display: block` and `text-align: center`, create utility classes that you can reuse on any element where those properties are applied.

I agree that the bloated markup takes some getting used to, but you may find freedom in having more consistency in selector specificity. This is the approach I take personally, and I also like how the CSS ends up basically documenting the structure of the module without actually coupling your CSS to the DOM structure.